# AS3 - Read contents from .ini file

Tags: actionscript-3, air, adobe

I have an AIR application that I am wanting to open and read contents from a .ini file that has some properties in it. I've looked around online and can't find anything - seems most of what Adobe had has been expired (LoadVars, PropertyLoader, etc.) Any suggestions? thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use either [`URLLoader`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html#includeExamplesSummary) or a combination of [`File` and `FileStream`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html#open())